# How should I configure Webpack for a react website to be able to use it without a server

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm building a react website. The goal for it is to be able to simply put the finished website on a USB key and be able to use it on a computer without any internet access.

I'm using react v16.6. I've already tried to simply open the `build/index.html` file but I received a few `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///static/...` and the page was blank.
This projects is using a JSON file, pictures and videos.

I don't really know where I should go from here to be able to this.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on some of your details, I'm assuming you're using create-react-app.

If you read the error message or look in build.html you'll see that the built site is trying to load your javascript from `/build/static/js/...`. This would effectively be trying to load the files from the root of the file system, not the current directory. You can set `"homepage": "."` in package.json and the built site will load the files correctly. This is documented in the message that you get when you do `npm run build`, which also links to https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment for more details.

Comment: That was way easier than I thought! Thanks